# Enable 1440p on CentOS 6 (VirtualBox Guest)

Tags: centos, virtualbox, resolution

I'm attempting to increase my resolution to 1440p on an existing CentOS VM. Currently, the display options only show up to 1080p under CentOS (guest OS, [screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pNQA.png)), but I am able to run 1440p on Windows 7 (host OS, [screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVTTR.png)). Virtual Box Linux guest additions 4.3.20 are installed (the latest version). I looked around already for suggestions on fixing this and found some people suggesting that I manually include the resolution. I ran the following commands with results included:

```
# cvt 2560 1440
2560x1440 59.96 Hz (CVT 3.69M9) hsync: 89.52 kHz; pclk: 312.25 MHz
Modeline "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync

# xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 64 x 64, current 5760 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
VBOX0 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1440x1050      60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.0  
   640x480        60.0  
VBOX1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1440x1050      60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.0  
   640x480        60.0  
VBOX2 connected 1920x1080+3840+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1440x1050      60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.0  
   640x480        60.0  

# xrandr --addmode VBOX0 "2560x1440_60.00"
xrandr: cannot find mode "2560x1440_60.00"
```

I'm not sure what steps to take at this point to increase the resolution. I'm using displayport on the monitors, the latest version of VirtualBox, and CentOS 6.6 64-Bit. Anything to point me in the right direction would be helpful. Thanks.

UPDATE: I found further information that I needed another command, so I tried the following with no success:

```
# xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync

# xrandr --addmode VBOX0 "2560x1440_60.00"
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  34
  Current serial number in output stream:  35
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem, so I wanted to share the steps I took to fix it.

The issue that I was stuck on was that the VirtualBox video settings were limiting me to 1080p or less, so I had to run the following command in my host OS (Windows 7). Do this while the VM is offline.

```
> VBoxManage setextradata "Web Dev" CustomVideoMode1 2560x1440x32
```

I booted the VM and reentered the following (new modes don't stay between boots):

```
# xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync

# xrandr --addmode VBOX0 "2560x1440_60.00"
# xrandr --addmode VBOX1 "2560x1440_60.00"
# xrandr --addmode VBOX2 "2560x1440_60.00"
```

Finally, I opened up the Display Preferences (System->Preferences->Display), and the new resolution was listed.

Note that I ran the 'xrandr --addmode' for each monitor, where VBOX0 is the name of the monitor as shown in the Display Preferences.

Hope that helps!